# Handling Exception after undefined function

Tags: javascript, security

is there any function working even with any exceptions ?

how it can be possible without removing `not_defined_func();` ?

```
<script>
not_defined_func();
try {
  console.log('hello')
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.message)
}
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried [`window.addEventListener("error", (event) => {})`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror)?

Comment: yes, but not working

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: `notdefined(); window.addEventListener("error", (event) => {console.log(13)}`

Comment: You have to register the eventListener before you trigger an error.

Comment: is there any resoultion without register the eventListener before you trigger an error ?

Comment: No. There is no other way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. You just have to put it inside of the try and catch block

```js
try {
  console.log('hello')
  not_defined_func();
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.message)
}
```

Comment: Is there any way without moving `not_defined_func();` to try catch block ?

Comment: There is no other method of catching the error that the function does not exist.

Comment: Can i run any function with getting error ?                                                                                                 Example ```<script>not_exist_function(); console.log('hello'); </script>```

Comment: You get the same error when running any function which does not exist. 
If I try calling "qwerty();" in the console. Then I get an error that it does not exist.

Comment: In this case you indeed don't need the try and catch blocks around the console.log